# How to speed up a high dimensional loop in python with numpy instead of pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, loops

This Loop does its work in 5 hours. How can i speed it up? I read something about using numpy functions instead of pandas. I tried as you can see but i am to new to python to do it right. The big thing here is the high dimensional data with 6000 columns. Every data is static, except of the random weights. How do i write better code?

````
import numpy as np
import os

#Covarinace Matrix in Pandas Dataframe 6000 columns  x 6000 rows
cov = input_table_1.copy() 

#Mean returns Pandas DataFrame  6000 columns x 1800 rows
mean_returns = input_table_2.copy().squeeze()

#Looping number
num_portfolios = 100.000

#Empty Resultsmatrix
results_matrix = np.zeros((len(cov.columns)+1, num_portfolios))
rf=0

#Loop corpus
for i in range(num_portfolios):

    #Random numbers between 0 and 1 for every column
    weights = np.random.uniform(0,1,len(cov.columns))
    
    #Ensure sum of all random numbers is = 1
    weights /= np.sum(weights)

    #Some easy math operations
    portfolio_return = np.sum(mean_returns * weights) * 252
    portfolio_std = np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov, weights))) * np.sqrt(252)
    sharpe_ratio = (portfolio_return - rf) / portfolio_std
    
    #write sharpe_ratio in result matrix as result for every loop
    results_matrix[0,i] = sharpe_ratio

    #iterate through the weight vector and add data to results array
    for j in range(len(weights)):
        results_matrix[j+1,i] = weights[j]

#output table as pandas data frame
output_table = pd.DataFrame(results_matrix.T,columns=['sharpe'] + [ticker for ticker in list(cov.columns)] )```
````

Comment: Have you used tensorflow? In there you have numpy library which is optimized to to the calculation which you have shown here [https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tf_numpy]

Comment: Thank you, i will try that and post the results.

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana I have tried a lot of things. First I replaced all my numpy NP with the tnp from tensorflow and get it work. I posted it as new post downwards. The sad thing is: Nothing got better. I had to leave the most thing in numpy, beacause of errors. Can you view over my Code? Maybe i missed some important steps? I mixed it up with some suggestions from Glauco.

Answer (score 0):

there is not a generic way to do that, first of all you must identify *where* your code is slow, and after that you can apply optimization.

First of all you have nested loop so complexity is O(n^2) not a bid deal here, because lot of work can be done using vectorial approach.

In python creation of new object is slow, so for example, if it can be stored in ram, the first np.random.uniform  can be done one time and consumed during the cycle.

nested iterator, can be done in vectorial mode, this seem the best candidates for performance.

Anyway i suggest to use a tool like [*perf_tool*](https://github.com/glaucouri/perf_tool) that will guide you exactly on the slow piece of code [*]

[*] i'm the main developer of this tool.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Two questions: Did you mean something like this for the random numbers:  pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1., size=(6000,1800 ))) ? But how could i implement it in the code? Second question: I do not know how to code your suggestions for "nested iterator, can be done in vectorial mode"- can you give me a hint? I will try your perf_tool for further investigation of my code :-)

Comment: Yes Adam,

`<untested>`
`multi_randoms = np.random.normal(0, 1., size=(num_portfolios,len(cov.columns) ))`
`for i in range(num_portfolios):`
`    #Random numbers between 0 and 1 for every column`
`    weights = multi_randoms[i] `

for the internal loop:

`#iterate through the weight vector and add data to results array`
`results_matrix[:,i] = np.roll(weights, 1) # here there some king of shifting (1 or -1) `

this is an example of vectorial version, this is more efficient.

Comment: Thank you @Glauco. I did what you have said. And now I know which part in my Code is slow. It is the vol_arr[x] = ... part. PreGenerating a the Random number is a very good Idea, which opened one very big quaestion in my mind. Why should i do all this thing in a loop? Isnt there a way to do multiplications in one step with the multi_randoms Dataframe? I posted one way of multitasking which halfed the time to 2,5 hours for 100k rounds . I posted it downwards. Is there a way to do this much better?

Comment: Sure Adam, using numpy you will have best result using array programming, but there are some important changes in approach. good luck

Answer (score 0):

@AmilaMGunawardana Here is my first try with tensorflow, but i is not fast enough. At the end i waited 5 hours for 100.000 rounds. Maybe i have to do something better?
Perftool showed me that evrything in the code is fast, except the Part:

vol_arr[x] = tnp.sqrt(tnp.dot(multi_randoms[x].T, np.dot(covData*252, multi_randoms[x]))) --> This part takes 90% of the execution Time.

````
covData = input_table_1.copy() 

#Mean returns Pandas DataFrame  6000 columns x 1800 rows
returns = input_table_2.copy().squeeze()

#Looping number
num_portfolios = 100000

rf=0

#print("mean_returns: ", mean_returns)
#print("cov2: ", cov2)
#print("cov: ", cov)

all_weights = np.zeros((num_ports, len(returns.columns))) #tnp.zeros([num_ports,len(returns.columns)], dtype=tnp.float32) #np.zeros((num_ports, len(returns.columns)))
ret_arr = pd.to_numeric(np.zeros(num_ports))#tnp.zeros(num_ports, dtype=tnp.float32)# pd.to_numeric(np.zeros(num_ports))
vol_arr = pd.to_numeric(np.zeros(num_ports))#tnp.zeros(num_ports, dtype=tnp.float32)
sharpe_arr = pd.to_numeric(np.zeros(num_ports))#tnp.zeros(num_ports, dtype=tnp.float32)
multi_randoms = np.random.normal(0, 1., size=(num_portfolios,len(covData.columns) ))
@perf_tool('main')
def main():

    for x in range(num_ports):

        with PerfTool('preparation1'):
            # Save weights
            all_weights[x,:] = multi_randoms[x]

        with PerfTool('preparation2'):
            # Expected return
            ret_arr[x] = tnp.sum( (mean_returns * multi_randoms[x] * 252))

        with PerfTool('preparation3'):
            # Expected volatility
            vol_arr[x] = tnp.sqrt(tnp.dot(multi_randoms[x].T, np.dot(covData*252, multi_randoms[x])))

        with PerfTool('preparation4'):
            # Sharpe Ratio
            sharpe_arr[x] = ret_arr[x] - rf /vol_arr[x]
    
PerfTool.set_enabled()
main()   
PerfTool.show_stats_if_enabled()```
````

Answer (score 0):

This showes up one way of getting better with parallel loading. How could i get rid of the loop? Is there a way to do this calculations in just one step with using all_weights Dataframe once instead of looping over it?

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from perf_tool import PerfTool, perf_tool
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, parallel_backend

#Covarinace Matrix in Pandas Dataframe 6000 columns  x 6000 rows
covData = input_table_1.copy() 

#Mean returns Pandas DataFrame  6000 columns x 1800 rows
mean_returns = input_table_2.copy().squeeze()

#Looping number
num_ports = 100000

all_weights = np.zeros((num_ports, len(mean_returns.columns)))
#multi_randoms = np.random.random(size=(len(df.columns) ))
for x in range(num_ports):
    weights = np.array(np.random.random(len(mean_returns.columns)))
    weights = weights/np.sum(weights)
    all_weights[x,:] = weights


#print(weights)
#weights = np.array(np.random.random(len(returns.columns)))
#print(all_weights)
#print("cov2 type: ", type(cov2))
#cov = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0, 1., size=(600,600)))
#print("cov type: ", type(cov))

rf=0

#print("mean_returns: ", mean_returns)
#print("cov2: ", cov2)
#print("cov: ", cov)

#all_weights = np.zeros((num_ports, len(returns.columns)))
ret_arr = pd.to_numeric(np.zeros(num_ports))
vol_arr = pd.to_numeric(np.zeros(num_ports))
sharpe_arr = pd.to_numeric(np.zeros(num_ports))

#@perf_tool('main')

#@jit(parallel=True)
def test(x):

    #for x in range(num_ports):

        #with PerfTool('preparation1'):
            # Weights
            #weights = np.array(np.random.random(len(returns.columns)))
        #with PerfTool('preparation2'):
            #weights = weights/np.sum(weights)

        #with PerfTool('preparation3'):
            # Save weights
            weights= all_weights[x]
            
        #with PerfTool('preparation4'):
            # Expected return
            ret_arr[x] = np.sum( (mean_returns * weights * 252))
        #with PerfTool('preparation5'):
            # Expected volatility
            vol_arr[x] =   np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(covData*252, weights)))

        #with PerfTool('preparation6'):
            # Sharpe Ratio
            return x, ret_arr[x] - rf /vol_arr[x]
            #sharpe_arr[x] = (np.sum( (mean_returns * all_weights * 252)) - rf) /(np.sqrt(np.dot(all_weights.T, np.dot(covData*252, all_weights))))
    
#PerfTool.set_enabled()


sharpe= []
weighttable= []
weighttable, sharpe= zip(*Parallel(n_jobs=-1)([delayed(test)(i) for i in range(num_ports)]))```
````